# put one picture in another and keep in the center with css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to keep my overlay "Play" button in the exact center of another pictures on every resolution display.

My best result is :

```css
.posForHover {
  position: relative;
}

.posForHover:hover .btnPlayHover {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.opaShadSelect:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.btnPlayHover {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24%;
  left: 34%;
  background: url(https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/03/4/1516308587-
 video-play-icon.png) center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 172px !important;
  width: 172px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <a class="" href="#">
    <div class="posForHover">
      <img class="img-responsive img-rounded opaShadSelect" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/J3kd6y6e1mg/maxresdefault.jpg">
      <span class=" btnPlayHover"></span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

But is not perfect when I switch to display resolution

Test on https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/41899/

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `transform` and `position:absolute` combination to vertically and horizontally center the button

```css
.posForHover {
  position: relative;
}
img{display:block;max-width:100%;}
.posForHover:hover .btnPlayHover {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.opaShadSelect:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.btnPlayHover {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: url(https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/03/4/1516308587-video-play-icon.png) center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 172px !important;
  width: 172px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <a class="" href="#">
    <div class="posForHover">
      <img class="img-responsive img-rounded opaShadSelect" src=" https://i.ytimg.com/vi/J3kd6y6e1mg/maxresdefault.jpg">
      <span class="btnPlayHover"></span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect, I never realy know what is usage for "Translate",  thanks you !